# ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure NPE while invoking getVisibility()

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-appcompat, android-tablayout, android-framelayout

Crashlytics data for my app shows a Null Pointer exception crash on FrameLayout.onMeasure().

I cannot see my application traces in the logs so cannot say for sure which Activity is crashing but the main activity consists of a TabLayout + Viewpager with 5 Fragments.
The crash logs are as below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:193)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:135)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18866)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18866)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18866)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18866)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2650)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18866)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2104)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1220)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1456)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6017)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Could this be some bug in the AppCompat v7 library? 
Or am I doing something wrong with the Tablayout + Viewpager combination

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the log the error is clear :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
```

You are trying to **call a method on a null object**, which is throwing the Null Pointer Exception.
My wild guess goes that you're trying to get the visibility of an object with `getVisiblity()` on your `onMeasure()` method, and since that very object is not yet instantiated (in other words, holds a null reference), it its throwing the exception.

*I have had a similar case on a **ViewPager***. Basically, I had not yet swiped/moved to the specific view and since that view was not yet constructed, I was calling a method on it, thus crashing the app.

Can you post the code snippet that includes that **onMeasure()** part so I can help you debug it?

Regards,

Comment: Ricardo, thanks for your comment!

I am not calling onMeasure() explicitly from my code but I feel I may be passing some null view when the system tries to initialise my tab layout + view pager .
Below is the Gist link to my code for initialising the views. I am not sure which part calls the onMeasure() method.
In case you find something suspicious which could cause passing of null object to FrameLayout’s onMeasure() method please let me know:

https://gist.github.com/vishyrich/014cad13b37cb7896d805d0e1ed9e6b8